# Passing a list created in one variable to another variable inside a class (PYTHON)

Tags: python, maya

I don´t understand why my list dosn´t get returned to the class and stay there after i call my second function, here is my code:

```
class ShockAbsorber:
    '''create Proxy, based of 2 locators'''
    def createProxy(self):
        self.allLoc = {}
        self.allLoc["CylinderLoc"] = pm.spaceLocator (n = "Cylinder_Loc")
        self.allLoc["PistonLoc"] = pm.spaceLocator (n = "Piston_Loc", p =[0,30,0])
        pm.CenterPivot()

    '''create bones on locators'''
    def createRig(self):
        for name,loc in self.allLoc.items():
            print Loc
```

I have an interface on a separete file that create 2 buttons one for each function.

```
    #define button Create Proxy
def CreateProxyPressed(self):
    csa = sa.ShockAbsorber() 
    csa.createProxy()

#define button Create Proxy
def CreateRigPressed(self):
    csa = sa.ShockAbsorber() 
    csa.createRig()
```

If I run my code I recive this error message:

```
AttributeError: ShockAbsorber instance has no attribute 'allLoc'
```

I hope this is enought information for you to understand my problem, I´m besically writing a tool For "Autodesk Maya". I´m pretty sure my concept is correct, so what I´m I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

P.S. I´m sorry guys for the confusion but I now edited my code to be correct after you spotted my typo!

Comment: In `CreateRigPressed` you create a new instance of `ShockAbsorber` and call `csa.createRig()`. This instance has no `allLoc`.

Comment: Ok got it, thank you!
Solution would be this on my button functions:

`code` #define button Create Proxy
 def CreateProxyPressed(self):
  self.csa = sa.ShockAbsorber() 
  self.csa.createProxy()
 
 #define button Create Proxy
 def CreateRigPressed(self):
  self.csa.createRig()

Answer (score 0):

You need to store `allLoc` in the class instance, instead of returning it:

```
def createProxy(self, *args):
    allLoc = {}
    allLoc["CylinderLoc"] = pm.spaceLocator (n = "Cylinder_Loc")
    allLoc["PistonLoc"] = pm.spaceLocator (n = "Piston_Loc", p =[0,30,0])
    pm.CenterPivot()
    self.allLoc = allLoc
```

Comment: I´m sorry you are absolutly right about that ( i forgot to change that bit of code after many try), but this is not solving the same problem. (I´ll edit my code anyway to see if you understand better.

Answer (score 0):

`createProxy` needs to set `self.allLoc`. You are setting the local name `allLoc` only.